# Copy, paste and delete row/rows in protected excel worksheet with VBA codes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that is protected with or without password to prevent users accidentally delete formulas in cells that are required to perform necessary calculations. I would like to enable the users to copy and paste rows or delete rows.

I am new to vba. As a starting point, ideally, I would like a vba code to work in the background along these lines.

**For Copy and Paste**

1) Unrpotect the worksheet when row or rows are selected
2) copy the selected row/rows
3) Allow the user to paste above/below any rows as they wish
4) Protect the worksheet

**For Deleting Row/Rows**
1) Unprotect the worksheet upon either right clicking of the mouse or clicking of the "Delete" after the row/rows required to be deleted is/are selected
2) Protect the worksheet

Below are the lines of code I have started toying with but I think I am a long way away from what they need to be. Any response would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPasteDeleteRowsInProtectedSheet()

'line for code for selected row/rows
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'line for code for selected row where the above selected row/rows to be pasted above
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Sean

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnKey) should be good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks Imran. This will be a good start, see where it gets me.